# Update part of object in Ionic Storage key/value pair

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic Storage DB with the following key/value pair:

`Key: settingsJSON
 Value: {toggleDates: false, toggleIndicator: false, toggleRepayments: false}`

Is there any way to update part of the object (i.e set `toggleDates` to `true`) without overriding the rest of object stored in the value?

I've tried:

```
 let settingsTemp = JSON.stringify({toggleDates: true});
 this.storage.set('settingsJSON', settingsTemp)
```

But this updates the entire object to `{toggleDates: true}`.

I've also tried:

```
this.storage.set('settingsJSON.toggleDates', true)
```

But this just creates a new key/value named `settingsJSON.toggleDates`.

Comment: You could `newArray = ...get('settingsJSON')`, update `newArray.toggleDates = true;` to whatever value, and then `...set('settingsJSON', newArray)` with the whole array, utilizing the previous value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
// Get the entire data
this.storage.get('settingsJSON').then(valueStr => {
    let value = valueStr ? JSON.parse(valueStr) : {};

     // Modify just that property
     value.toggleDates = true;

     // Save the entire data again
     this.storage.set('settingsJSON', JSON.stringify(value));
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks. I didn't the promise because I get the value with `navParams.get()` from the previous page, so it worked even before your edit.